# How do I access a user defined variable as defined at the top of a Makefile.am file?

Tags: gnu-make, autotools, autoconf, automake

Specifically, I want to do something along the following lines. For a Makefile.am script that defines how a library file should be built, I want to be able to access a common library name throughout. For example, assuming I want the name of the library to be called 'name', I might start with the following variable:

```
LIBNAME = name
```

Then I might have something like this:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = lib$(LIBNAME).la
```

But then automake starts to complain when I want to do something like the following:

```
lib$(LIBNAME)_la_SOURCES = file1.cpp file2.cpp
lib$(LIBNAME)_la_LIBADD = ...
```

Is anything like this possible using some other syntax so that I don't have to multiply repeat the name of the library?

Cheers,

Ben.

Comment: Are you hoping to give the user the ability to change the name of the installed library, or merely to reduce repetition in the Makefile.am?

Comment: I simply wish to reduce repetition. I have lots of Makefile.am files scattered around and I'm trying to figure out ways to make them all as generic as possible.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it if you define your variable at `configure` time instead of in the Makefile itself.

For example, in `configure.ac`:

```
LIBNAME=name
AC_SUBST(LIBNAME)
```

Then you can access it in `Makefile.am` like this:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = lib@LIBNAME@.la
```

Comment: @WilliamPursell even if you create your makefiles with text substitutions like `lib@LIBNAME@.la`?

Comment: This solution cannot work!  Automake needs the name of the primary when it parses Makefile.am, so a configure time substitution won't solve anything.

Comment: It seems to work just fine here: https://github.com/ptomato/osxcart/blob/gtk3/osxcart/Makefile.am (which I copied from another library, I forget where)

Comment: This is really slick.  I am surprised that automake allows `@` characters in the name, and looking through the automake mailing list archive I haven't yet found a discussion on whether this was intentional, but it is certainly a nice feature.  It's truly a shame that I have but one upvote to give.

Comment: However, I would recommend `AC_SUBST([LIBNAME],[${LIBNAME:-defaultname}])`

Answer (score 0):

> Then I might have something like this:

```
LIBNAME = name
lib_LTLIBRARIES = lib$(LIBNAME).la
lib$(LIBNAME)_la_SOURCES = file1.cpp file2.cpp
lib$(LIBNAME)_la_LIBADD = ...
```

IFAIK, this will not work with automake. I don't think it's possible to do it using some other syntax, either.